# Bash call function from another file while using symbolic link

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've create two bash files and place these in the same project folder. I've linked bash file one with this command `ln -s ~/{path_to_bash_file_one} x`. Now I want to use a function from bash file two inside bash file one like below.

**Bash file one:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# include files
source  ./bash_file_two.sh

echo "hello " ${someFunc}
```

**Bash file two:**

```
#!/bin/bash

someFunc () {
    echo "someone"
}
```

When I call it the terminal returns this error `/usr/local/bin/x: line 135: someoneFunc: command not found`. So my question is what's the right path to use when a file that's linked by a symbolic link?

Comment: check your casing - there's a capital `O` in someOneFunc and not in the second script

Comment: Your link is named 'x', but you are sourcing a file named 'utils.sh'.  How are the two related?

Comment: I forgot to check this snippet which I've created quickly sorry for that. I've updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

```
/usr/local/bin/x: line 135: someoneFunc: command not found
```

has got nothing to do with symbolic link imho.

Change bash file two to

```
someoneFunc () {
    echo "someone"
}
```

Source it

```
. /path/to/bash/file2
./path/to/x # Then run x
```

Also, the usage

```
echo "hello " someOneFunc
```

doesn't look right at first sight. Did you, instead , look for command substitution

```
echo "hello " $(someOneFunc)
```

Comment: If showcasing best practices, better to put the command substitution *inside* the quotes.

Comment: (I'd also suggest explaining the *why* of suggested changes -- ie. what they fix. Removing the shebang, if that's what you meant by "change bash file two to:", arguably could go either way -- it's not *used* when something is sourced, but then, it's sometimes handy as a hint for editor syntax highlighting).